# Spelling mistake for singular bounty?

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounty, new-nav, user-interface

Not sure that "bountie" is an alternative spelling of "bounty":

> [image: misspelled bounty]

Even if it is, that doesn't seem too standard.

Comment: yay pluralization bugs

Comment: Oh boy, that's the second pluralization bug in the last couple days... [Beware Atwood's wrath](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/63791#63791).

Comment: Surely it is correct in Australia?  Put a bountie on the barbie mate.

Comment: So you only have to drop an S and its singular?

Comment: @Matt It’s just one more pluralization crise in a long list of them.

Comment: I was more commenting on the logic that got to this point. But yeah.... not the first post like this in recent history.

Comment: In Canada, one Mounty, two Mounties?

Comment: Yep, another inacurracie in the pluralization code.

Comment: Holy moly... 30+ upvotes for a pluralization bug? I wonder what kind of activity a *real* bug would draw...

Comment: @eykanal: Two upvotes, a downvote, and a comment missing the point?

Comment: You must be new to Stack Exchange. Upvotes reflect the number of people who are capable of understanding the question. Which, quite typically, is the exact opposite of reflecting importance, quality, or urgency. Look up [Parkinson's law of triviality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson's_law_of_triviality).

Answer (score 5):

At least it does not say 1 bountieS... Should be fixed in next build (build rev `2015.11.13.3870` on MSO, `2015.11.13.2982` on SO).